# Apache: does a ProxyPass proxy a <Location> itself, or just the *contents* of that Location?

Tags: apache, mod-proxy

I know, sounds like a stupid question, but bear with me. In this setup:

```
<Location /a/b/c/d>
  ProxyPass http://localhost:8080/a/b/c/d
</Location>
<Location /a/>
  ProxyPass http://localhost:8080/
</Location>
```

If I access `https://example.com/a/b/c/d` the `mod_proxy` debug shows that the second proxy is being used (it's not very verbose, but this appears to be what it's saying). And, in fact, I'm seeing an access to `http://localhost:8080/b/c/d`, which won't work (another module must see *exactly* the path in the first `ProxyPass`).

There's no ordering problem here, so I have no idea what's going on. The docs aren't very clear on this, because they always use a suffix (extra path component) in the examples, like this one, where an access to `http://example.com/mirror/foo/bar` is proxied to `http://backend.example.com/bar`:

```
<Location "/mirror/foo/">
    ProxyPass "http://backend.example.com/"
</Location>
```

So what happens to an access to `http://example.com/mirror/foo`?